# Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know that many had this problem, and solved it, but even with their solutions, I've gotten no luck..

I tried exporting my localhost phpadmin to my webserver, and i got:

```
SQL query:

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

Local phpmyadmin:

> Server type: MariaDB
>
> Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
>
> Version: 4.5.2

Webhost phpmyadmin:

> Version: 2.11.4

Comment: I just noticed the version difference. Is there a way i can import my db to an old version?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Downloaded MYSQL workbench, logged into my local database, and exported it from the program. Then, i simply imported the file, and it worked!